# .NET MAUI - Rich Text

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, maui, rtf

I'm building an app using .Net 7.0 and MAUI. I've been struggling to find a way to edit and present RTF but I can't seem to find a way rather than incorporating a WebView with some editor like Summernote or CKEditor etc, something I don't want to do for a number of reasons.

Is there a way to do this in an Editor or Entry component? Is there a RTF editor component, or something similar, preferably open source, for this purpose? I know Telerik and DevExpress have similar components but they are way our of my budget.

I tried to use a handler for doing this but it didn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. Product recommendations are off-topic. If you are trying to build a component we need to see your code.

Comment: I don't think that what you (we) want is supported in MAUI yet without "paying the piper". I have a cross-platform RTF app but I'm still using Xamarin + WinForms to achieve that objective. I wanted to mention the Syncfusion [Free Community License](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) you might qualify for. For Xamarin they have a WebView based RTF editor and some doc conversions. So I'm currently using platform redirection to accomplish the goal. If MAUI is the requirement I think it's sit-and-wait.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/8087

Answer (score 1):

For now, the MAUI does not have a native rich text editor. But you can use WebView control and loading opensource web RichTextEditor in blazor.

Here is the article about the RTF on the Maui you can refer to [MAUI should have a RichTextBox equivalent rich text editor](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/8087).